# Google Apps Script EventHandlers with userdata

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps script to make some custom UI for a google spreadsheet.

I'm trying to make an abstract 'wizard' UI that has an arbitary array of panels and then a 'back' and 'next' button at the bottom that changes the visibility of the panels depending on which 'page' you are on.

I need some kind of mechanism so that when you move from one page of the wizard to the next, I can call a function on the current 'page' to say "I'm moving away from you now, please save your state", and similarly to the next 'page' to say "Set yourself up, you're about to become visible" (something like onShow(), onHide()).

However I'm struggling to work out how to do that from within the event handlers for the back and next buttons. As far as I can see it's only really easy to access UI elements or to pass strings (via 'hidden' ui elements) into the event handlers.

This is the pertinent code that I have at the moment:

```
/*
*********************************************************************
*/
function createWizard(pages) {
  app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var currIdx = app.createHidden("currentPanelIndex", 0).setId("CurrentPanelIndex");
  var minIdx = app.createHidden("minPanelIndex", 0);
  var maxIdx = app.createHidden("maxPanelIndex", pages.length);
  app.add(currIdx);
  app.add(minIdx);
  app.add(maxIdx);

  var buttPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var backButton = app.createButton("Back"); 
  var nextButton = app.createButton("Next"); 
  buttPanel.add(backButton).add(nextButton);

  var mainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    pages[i].setId("Panel"+i).setVisible(false);
    mainPanel.add(pages[i]);
  }

  mainPanel.add(buttPanel);
  mainPanel.setCellVerticalAlignment(buttPanel, UiApp.VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
  mainPanel.setCellHorizontalAlignment(buttPanel, UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);

  app.add(mainPanel);

  // create handler to respond to events
  var clickHandler = app.createServerClickHandler("doBack")
    .addCallbackElement(currIdx)
    .addCallbackElement(minIdx)
    .addCallbackElement(maxIdx);
  backButton.addClickHandler(clickHandler);  
  var clickHandler = app.createServerClickHandler("doNext")
    .addCallbackElement(currIdx)
    .addCallbackElement(minIdx)
    .addCallbackElement(maxIdx);
  nextButton.addClickHandler(clickHandler);

  updateVisibility(currIdx, minIdx, maxIdx)
}

/*
*********************************************************************
*/
function doBack(eventInfo) {
  app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var parameter = eventInfo.parameter;
  var currentPanel = Math.round(Number(parameter.currentPanelIndex));
  var minPanel = Math.round(Number(parameter.minPanelIndex));
  var maxPanel = Math.round(Number(parameter.maxPanelIndex));

  if (currentPanel > minPanel) {
    currentPanel--;
    // Store the new value
    app.getElementById("CurrentPanelIndex").setValue(String(currentPanel));

    updateVisibility(currentPanel);
  }

  return app;
}

/*
*********************************************************************
*/
function doNext(eventInfo) {
  app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var parameter = eventInfo.parameter;
  var currentPanel = parseInt(parameter.currentPanelIndex);
  var minPanel = Math.round(Number(parameter.minPanelIndex));
  var maxPanel = Math.round(Number(parameter.maxPanelIndex));
  Logger.log(currentPanel);

  if (currentPanel < maxPanel) {
    currentPanel++;
    // Store the new value
    app.getElementById("CurrentPanelIndex").setValue(String(currentPanel));

    updateVisibility(currentPanel, minPanel, maxPanel);
  }

  return app;
}

/*
*********************************************************************
*/
function updateVisibility(currentPanel, minPanel, maxPanel)
{
  for (var i = minPanel; i < maxPanel; i++) {
    if (i == currentPanel) {
      app.getElementById("Panel"+i).setVisible(true);
      // I want to do something like panel[i].onShow()
    }
    else {
      app.getElementById("Panel"+i).setVisible(false);
      // I want to do something like panel[i].onShow()
    }
  }  
}
```

Note that I don't think I can extend the UI elements to be able to have a 'onShow' or 'onHide' callback. I also can't see how I could pass a callback as a string!

I can post more code if necessary, but I'm quite happy to start again from scratch if I'm approaching this the wrong way, so my current implementation details are relatively unimportant.

Disclaimer, I'm pretty good at C++, C#, Lua etc, but pretty much a newbie at JavaScript, so I may be missing something entirely obvious!

Comment: While its doable you will find many limitations in uiservice. Use htmlService instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is maybe too complicated... All the widgets that you create in a  user interface can be created from the start in different panels, then your handler function only has to "play" with their visibility. From the user pov it's like the UI is completely different but you have a unique callbackElement that contains all the widgets.
Here is a [small very basic example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxlPTVLSLfO3d1w2vSrMzzh57p9DJM6ivCIHiIfTB2AKqubSs1L/exec) that I suggested long ago that simulates tab panels based on the same principle.

The 4 panels are in one single vertical panel so that each of them takes exactly the same place, giving the illusion that the content is changing.

I don't have time to suggest a full demo code but tell me if this approach could suit your needs.

---

**edit** following your comment :

Since you already have handlers to handle `previous/next` on two buttons what I'd do would be to have the 2 same buttons reproduced on every "page", all of them having the same 2 handlers but different IDs. This way the layout would stay the same but you could know which "page" did fire the handler function using `e.parameter[source]`. If you know the page and if all your widgets have a coherent indexing there is no limit to what specific action you can take.
For example, switching from page 3 to page 4 would be identified because the source of the handler function would be `button_next_3` and (always for example) write data from this panel to sheet 3 on your SS.

Hoping I'm clear enough, I don't see any limitation in such a concept. Do you ?

Comment: That's effectively what I have at the moment, using a bunch of different panels and toggling the visibility in order to show 'different pages'. However the key point is that those pages need to perform an operation when they are shown (or hidden) and I can't work out the mechanism for that.

Comment: What kind of operation and how is that an issue?  Do you miss some data?

Comment: I guess the simplest example is to write the data entered in the wizard into some cells in the spreadsheet. The wizard framework as a whole shouldn't care about the contents of the pages, those pages themselves should be responsible for putting the data in the right place.

Comment: I commented in my answer  to get more space :-)

Comment: Best suggestion so far :-) I think that's probably workable (though duplication of buttons is a bit grim). I wonder whether I might get away with having the same buttons, but then having the page initialisation set the IDs for the buttons... food for thought, I'll see what I can crowbar in!